# Can you change the authority in a MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication after instantiating it?

Tags: python, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am working on a multi-tenant Azure AD application using the Client Credentials flow, and relying [MSAL for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) to obtain the tokens needed to call the MS Graph API. The application itself is a mixture of a deamon and web app, meaning that no users can be directly signed in, but either when invoked or periodically it needs to make the MS Graph API calls on their behalf. I have registered the application properly, and the admins have granted the application permissions for all the tenants.

Upon requesting the tokens as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-daemon#requesting-tokens) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=python), for the home tenant with the corresponding authority, I managed to successfully call the Graph API for a user within that tenant. However, when I tried to invoke MS Graph API for a user within the other tenant, (presumably as expected) it results in an erroneous response.

I am sure that the permissions have been granted because if I re-instantiate msal with a different authority or manually invoke the `/token` endpoint as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), I successfully retrieve the Graph API data for the corresponding user.

I have not posted any code as the questions are more related to the design and MSAL for Python itself. Also, to do the sanity check, I have tried directly setting the authority field within the instantiated msal app but that doesn't make a change. After a bit more digging in the MSAL source, I realised that it doesn't change because the [initialisation of the app creates the authority in the constructor](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/msal/application.py#L237), and the use of neither [`ConfidentialClientApplication(...).aquire_token_for_client(...)`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/msal/application.py#L1006), nor [`Client(...).aquireTokenForClient(...)`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/8ea9ba5b6850c305166bbdd02042922136870b89/msal/oauth2cli/oauth2.py#L559) on which the former relies, fiddles with the authority itself. Finally, I couldn't find any issues on the repository, anything in the docs, nor any questions on SO which were able to answer my question.

Therefore, as the tenants I need to interact with might change, and as I feel that instantiating the MSAL app every time I need to request an access token within my own endpoint creates a bit of an overhead, my questions are:

0. Am I missing something obvious?
1. Is it possible to change the authority after creating the msal instance?
2. If it is not possible, what would be the optimal way to handle the acquiring of access tokens for each tenant within this use case?

Thenk you in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have managed to find something which might be useful. It is a [sample flask app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/master/app.py) provided by Azure, in which msal app is created every time by invoking the `_build_msal_app()` method. Nonetheless, my question if this is the optimal way still remains, even though the answer is probably in line with Azure's implementation.

Comment: Did you see this sample: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/af5d63820a29786263b22f7ee7702077dccae2e4/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py?

Comment: @AllenWu Thanks! Yes, I saw it, but it is not completely the same use case as the program requires the access token only once. So it is not clear how it should look like when multiple tokens are needed.

Comment: I want to step back a bit. When you say multi-tenant app, is it [Multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) literally or it's just that you have multiple tenants to handle separately? In case of later you need to create different instance of MSAL application for each tenant and use the respective one based on your target tenant in the context. You can pre-create all the instances and keep it in dictionary.

Comment: @krishg thanks for the reply! I don't quite see the difference between the two multi-tenant definitions you mentioned, but yes - it does handle multiple tenants at any time. And keeping them in a dictionary might be a solution, but only if the dictionary is managed during run-time since I have no knowledge on new tenants which might sign up along the way. Cheers for the idea, might go with it! Nonetheless, it still feels like a bit of a hacky approach..

Comment: Difference between the 2 multi-tenant scenario I mentioned is first one is about the target tenant having a multi-tenant app (you might want read the link) and other tenants have given the access of that app in their tenants. So client always authenticate using that app using 'common' or 'organization' (yes those are special keywords) endpoint no matter what their origin tenant is to access resources of target tenant. While the later is you are just authenticating to different tenants using their tenant specific app separately.

Comment: Cheers again! I have read your link, but it sounded quite similar to the overall definition of tenancy on their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps). I can either not spot the difference because I perceive a multi-tenant app as a single application living in it's tenant and catering to multiple tenants (which fits both of your scenarios), or because I am misinterpreting/misunderstanding the second option you have mentioned. However, I might slightly see the source of confusion..

Comment: It is an application permissions type of app, so I need to use a specific `tenant_id` in the authority, and cannot use the `organisation` endpoint. Sorry for the confusion. But altogether, it is a multi-tenant app in the sense that it gets application permission from multiple other tenants, and then accesses their information on per-need basis. `organisation` and `common` are only used during authorisation afair, and when asking for `access_tokens` you must use a specific `tenant_id` and cannot use the general endpoints (was stuck on that one for a bit)